# Retrofit2 - Unable to create string from non-null response body

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, httpresponse

I'm attempting to make an API call then use it's response as a string. Thus far I am able to successfully get and log the response... however the string I'm attempting to create using the response is empty and I'm unsure why this might be happening.

Any suggestions are appreciated:

```
  api.getUser().enqueue(new API.SimpleCallback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ResponseBody data) {
            try {
                Log.d("RAW BODY", data.string());
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = App.sharedPrefs.edit();
                    String responseString =  data.string().toString();
                    editor.putString(NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES_ENABLED_STATUS,responseString);
                    editor.apply();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response body can be consumed only once.  https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html

In your code, you are attempting to consume the body multiple times.  (once when you log it, and another time when you try to put it in the shared preferences).

Instead do something like:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(ResponseBody responseBody) {
    String data = responseBody.string();
    Log.d("RAW_DATA", data);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(myKey, data);
}
```